# resolve: No such host is known?

Tags: c++, http, networking, boost

I am facing a strange issue while trying to resolve endpoints using boost resolver in c++.

Case:
I am trying to connect to a website http://localhostIpAddress/test/ using boost.
where local address of server is "172.34.22.11"(say).

I am facing the error saying "**resolve: No such host is known**"

But when I am connecting to say website like google.com its able to resolve and connect successfully.
Also,even when I try to open "http:://localhostIpAddress/test/" in a browser, it opens successfully.

below is my code:

```
int main()
{
        std::cout << "\nWebClient  is starting... \n";
        boost::asio::io_service IO_Servicehttp;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver Resolverhttp(IO_Servicehttp);
        std::string porthttp = "http";
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query Queryhttp("172.34.22.11/test/", porthttp);  
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator EndPointIteratorhttp = Resolverhttp.resolve(Queryhttp);

        g_ClientHttp = new HTTPClient(IO_Servicehttp, EndPointIteratorhttp);

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }
}
```

In HTTPClient.cpp

```
HTTPClient::HTTPClient(boost::asio::io_service& IO_Servicehttp, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator EndPointIterhttp)
: m_IOServicehttp(IO_Servicehttp), m_Sockethttp(IO_Servicehttp),m_EndPointhttp(*EndPointIterhttp)
{
    std::cout << "\n Entered: HTTPClient ctor \n";
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endhttp;
    boost::system::error_code error= boost::asio::error::host_not_found;

    try
    {
        while (error && EndPointIterhttp != endhttp) //if error go to next endpoint
        {
            m_Sockethttp.async_connect(m_EndPointhttp,boost::bind(&HTTPClient::OnConnect_http, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++EndPointIterhttp));
        }
        if(error)
            throw boost::system::system_error(error);
    }

    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    m_IOServicehttp.run();
}
```

I have gone through a lot of website directed by google but haven't found anything related to this issue.
Any help or tip will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The hostname being resolved is invalid.  Try changing the resolver's query host to "172.34.22.11".  In the URL, "http://172.34.22.11/test/":

- "http" is the protocol
- "172.34.22.11" is the host which needs resolved
- "/test/" is the path

At a high level, network communication occurs between the client and the server (host) over TCP.  The client will create an HTTP request, include the path as part of the request, and write the complete request to a TCP socket.  The server will read the HTTP request from a TCP socket, process the request based on the path, then write an HTTP response to the client over TCP.

---

Hostnames are concatenated with dots and specified to only allow:

- ASCII letters 'a' through 'z'
- digits
- hyphen

Hence, "172.34.22.11/test/" contains invalid characters, and will likely not resolve.  See [RFC952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952) and [RFC1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
I have tried resolving hostname - "172.34.22.11" already, and which works fine.
But my requirement is to send some data to /test/ , and in that case I need to get the complete URL "http://172.34.22.11/test/".
How shall I do that then? If you can direct me proper direction it would be really helpful, as I am novice in networking domain.

Comment: Also, while looking through stackoverflow posts I found every one suggesting to use POCO or CURL libraries for HTTP/HTTPS connection/data transfer. So does that mean boost is not a good choice for HTTP ? As I am using boost for other purppose in my application , hence I thought to use it for HTTP communication also.

Comment: @harry If the purpose is to get an understanding of the the protocol by writing an HTTP client, then the [Asio HTTP Client examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.http_client) may be a good place to start, and may help one understand how an HTTP request is sent to a host and not a URL.  On the other hand, if one merely needs to communicate via HTTP, then using a well-tested, mature, existing URL library, such as libcurl, would be a good idea.

Comment: I have some requirement to implement and it needs to send jason data to web hosted on a local server.
I am try to implement as well learn as its pretty new stuff for me.
I have already gone through examples given in Boost websites and based on that I was trying implement.Since I was already using boost libraries for project, I wanted to use it further for HTTP purpose also.So libcurl would be better choice for the requirement I mentioned? Also, is that cross platform like boost?

Comment: @harry Choosing tools is rarely as straight forward as one would hope when one considers all the factors, such as environment restrictions, licensing, integration costs, learning curve, support, familiarity, etc.  If I had to use JSON, I would prefer a JSON library instead of either Boost.PropertyTree or implementing a JSON parser with Boost.Spirit.  Similarly, if I had to use HTTP, I would prefer an HTTP library instead of implementing the HTTP protocol with Boost.Asio.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback.
I think you made your point pretty straight :)
Thoguh Jason format is not a problem for me but I will check Libcurl or Poco for http.